# How can I remove this open tab in finder?

Tags: mac, finder, mojave

I'm using macOS Mojave. This tab in the Finder (I don't know what it's called) keeps showing up, which is annoying me. How can I remove this tab (the one in the red circle in the image)?

[image: Finder image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Finder menu bar, click *View* and then *Hide Preview*

Comment: This is the right answer! If you still feel like it should be deleted, go ahead, but it correctly answers the question and is what I would have answered with had you not.

Comment: It was downvoted so I thought the person who asked the question wasn't satisfied with the answer.